# Rangy: focusNode is the parent of the anchorNode

Tags: javascript, rangy

I have a html:

```
<div class="container">
    Line 1<br>
    Line 2<br>
    Line 3<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    Line 7<br>
</div>
```

If my range is:

```
<div class="container">
    Line 1<br>
    Line 2<br> ---+
    Line 3<br>    |
    <br>          |
    <br>----------+
    Line 7<br>
</div>
```

Where anchorNode is correct text node "Line 2", but focus node ends up `<div class="container">...</div>`, despite visual selection stops at end of "Line 3".

What would be a sort of "official" way to get "Line 3" as focusNode?

One way I think of is getting mouse coordinates within container node and do the math traversing upwards while I'm getting some real text, but this just sounds wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could loop through `rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getNodes()`.